# Show div based on select value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a form that changes after the users makes a choice. 
If the user select "Option A" then show content of the div with the class "option1".

I have already done this with very simple jquery(see code below or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqexdk6s/4/)).
What I can't figure out is how to make it dynamic.

Here is how I would do it in my head:

1. Get all option values from "#select" and put into array.
2. Replace the content of "hideAll" function with the new array.
3. Make some kind of "for-each-function" that runs though the array and
   makes the if stament.

A little note: The option value are always the same as the div class.

```js
var hideAll = function() {
  $('.option1, .option2, .option3').hide();
}

$('#select').on('change', function() {
  hideAll();
  var category = $(this).val();
  console.log(category);
  if (category === 'option1') {
    $('.option1').show();
  }
  if (category === 'option2') {
    $('.option2').show();
  }
  if (category === 'option3') {
    $('.option3').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <label for="option">Options</label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <div class="option1" style="display:block;">
    <label for="countries">Countries</label>
    <select name="countries">
      <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
      <option value="norway">Norway</option>
      <option value="uk">UK</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="option2" style="display:none;">
    <label for="letters">Letters</label>
    <select name="letters">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="option3" style="display:none;">
    <label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
    <select name="numbers">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a loop at all, and you can just search for any div whose class begins with `option`:

```js
var hideAll = function() {
  $('div[class^=option]').hide();
}

$('#select').on('change', function() {
  hideAll();
  var category = $(this).val();

  $('.' + category).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<label for="option">Options</label>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div class="option1" style="display:block;">
<label for="countries">Countries</label>
<select name="countries">
  <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="uk">UK</option>
</select>
 </div>

<div class="option2" style="display:none;">
<label for="letters">Letters</label>
<select name="letters">
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="option3" style="display:none;">
<label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
<select name="numbers">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Give your option divs another class

```
<form method="post">
<label for="option">Options</label>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div class="option1 optiondiv" style="display:block;">
<label for="countries">Countries</label>
<select name="countries">
  <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="uk">UK</option>
</select>
 </div>

<div class="option2 optiondiv" style="display:none;">
<label for="letters">Letters</label>
<select name="letters">
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="option3 optiondiv" style="display:none;">
<label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
<select name="numbers">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Use your new class in `hideall`

```
var hideAll = function() {
    $('.optiondiv').hide();
}
```

Use the select value to display a block

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    hideAll();
    var category = $(this).val();
    $('.' + category).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yd5qsquL/

Comment: That's definitely a nicer approach if you're able to adjust the HTML. Always cleaner to act on a single class. *If* you need to work with the existing HTML as-is, see my answer - but go this way if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an easier way to tackle this. First, use a combination of IDs and classes for the HTML, and then use JQuery to handle the dynamic stuff for you.

**The HTML**

Note that I have added `class="option-grouping" id="option1"` etc to each of your divs. This is better semantic structure and makes the JQuery easier.

```
<form method="post">
<label for="option">Options</label>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div class="option-grouping" id="option1" style="display:block;">
<label for="countries">Countries</label>
<select name="countries">
  <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="uk">UK</option>
</select>
 </div>

<div class="option-grouping" id="option2" style="display:none;">
<label for="letters">Letters</label>
<select name="letters">
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="option-grouping" id="option3" style="display:none;">
<label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
<select name="numbers">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**The JQuery**

This is the cool part. With that all done, try this as your JQuery:

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    var category = $(this).val();
    /* Hide all the divs */
    $('.option-grouping').hide();
    /* Now unhide the selected options */
    $('#' + category).show();
});
```

Works a treat!

Comment: I should clarify that the reason it's better to use id="option1" rather than class="option1" is because IDs are for elements that are unique on a page, whereas classes are for elements that you expect to see repeated on a page.